# jTable and Sorting

Tags: java, swing

How do i sort jtable column using radio button?

my jtable is defaultTableModel not vectors.

I have already achieve when user press on column header, it will sort, now i have to implement using radio button..

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do a sort programmatically you add code like the following to your listener:

```
DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter());
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING) );
sorter.setSortKeys(list);
sorter.sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an actionlistener to the radiobutton, sort and set the tableModel.
The Vector argument is an input to defaultTableModel.

```
final JTable table = new JTable();
JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //sort your data here
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(sortedDate));
    table.repaint();// maybe revalidate too
  }
});
```