# sort JTable's entries without clicking on column header

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I've implemented row sorting on a JTable both using DefaultRowSorter and my custom defined row sorter class. All works fine clicking on the column header to sort the table.

But what about if I want to invoke a sort operation from inside my application code ( without clicking on the column header). Which method do I have to call ?

EDIT:

I initialize my tables row sorter this way:

```
public void buildRowSorter() {
        TableRowSorter<MyModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyModel>((MyModel)this.table.getModel());

        try {
            sorter.setComparator(0, new MyCustomComparator<Double>(sorter,0));
            sorter.setComparator(1, new MyCustomComparator<String>(sorter,1));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }
```

Now I would like, having a reference to the JTable (table), to retrieve the associated row sorter to a particular column of my model, and invoke a sort operation on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268124/jtable-and-sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as I can see you have a custom *comparator* (why does that keep a reference to the sorter? looks fishy) not a custom RowSorter.

The intended way to change sorting is to invoke toggleSortOrder(column) on RowSorter. For more fine-grained control you can need access to the DefaultRowSorter, f.i. its setSortKeys method.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `sort()` method of `DefaultRowSorter`.

Comment: I haven't a reference to a DefaultRowSorter. I edited my question try to explain it better.

Comment: @Overbose : You can get it as `DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter());`