# Sort a Java JTable by one column

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jTable and Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268124/jtable-and-sorting)

I have a Jtable with a header which automtically sort table by user click. Is it possible to reproduce the effect of user click on the header to make the table sort based on one column?
Actually I work with this:

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
```

Any better solution?

Comment: you right sory should I delete this?

Comment: No it's fine, it will get closed as a duplicate. You can leave it. If somebody runs a search with your words in the future, he will find your question and the duplicate more easily.